# What is the exact value of the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{2k}k^4/256^k$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

By Stirling's formula $n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}(n/e)^n$, we have
$$\binom{2k}k\sim\frac{4^k}{\sqrt{k\pi}}$$
and hence
$$\frac{\binom{2k}k^4}{256^k}\sim\frac1{k^2\pi^2}.\tag{1}$$
So the series
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}k^4}{256^k}\tag{2}$$
converges.

**QUESTION.** What is the exact value of the series $(2)$?

Your comments are welcome!

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+of+binom%282k%2Ck%29%5E4*1%2F256%5Ek+for+k+from+0+to+infinity) returns the value in terms of a hypergeometric function. Whether it has any more reasonable "closed form" - I don't know.

Comment: For any odd prime $p$, it is easy to see that $$\sum_{k=0}^{(p-1)/2}\frac{\binom{2k}k^4}{256^k}\equiv A_{(p-1)/2}\pmod{p^2},$$ where $A_n$ denotes the Apery number $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k^2\binom{n+k}k^2$.

Comment: You are essentially asking for Polya's fourth [random walk constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolyasRandomWalkConstants.html) $u(4)$, right? Apparently that's a known open problem.

Comment: sums $c_p=\sum_{k=0}^\infty 4^{-pk}\binom{2k}k^p$ can be evaluated in closed form for $p=1,2,3$, but not for larger $p$; for the case $p=3$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2151053/87355

Comment: Is this tractable by the WZ proof certificate method?

Comment: Looked at S. Finch's Books and Inverse Symbolic Calculator among others sources. This constant seems not to be known in closed form as an exact expression. Sum can be expressed either in terms of MeijerG function or Hypergeometric function as $$ S = \frac{1}{\pi^2}\cdot G_{4,4}^{4,1}( 1,1,1,1;\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};-1)$$ or $$ S =\ _4F_3( \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1,1,1;1)$$ respectively. First digits are  1.118636387164187068349619257525640916794857551529361191480618646924046289